# Cannot use Bower (without proxy)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bower, frontend, bower-install

I am not being able to make requests with bower, either installing packages or searching with `bower search`.

I tried to install a package and got the following on the terminal:

```
bower ENOTFOUND Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/flat-      ui failed: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND bower.herokuapp.com bower.herokuapp.com:443

Stack trace:
Error: Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/flat-ui failed: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND bower.herokuapp.com bower.herokuapp.com:443
at createError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/bower-registry-client/lib/util/createError.js:2:15)
at Request._callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/bower-registry-client/lib/lookup.js:97:29)
at self.callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/request/request.js:198:22)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
at Request.request.emit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/request-replay/index.js:69:33)
at Request.onRequestError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/request/request.js:820:8)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:310:9)

From previous event:
at PackageRepository.fetch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/core/PackageRepository.js:46:6)
at Manager._fetch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/core/Manager.js:323:51)
at Array.forEach (native)
at Manager.resolve (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/core/Manager.js:116:23)
at Project._bootstrap (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/core/Project.js:559:6)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/core/Project.js:75:21

Console trace:
Error
at StandardRenderer.error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/renderers/StandardRenderer.js:81:37)
at Logger.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/bin/bower.js:110:26)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Logger.emit (events.js:188:7)
at Logger.emit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/bower-logger/lib/Logger.js:29:39)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/commands/index.js:48:20
at _rejected (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:844:24)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:870:30
at Promise.when (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:1122:31)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:788:41)

System info:
Bower version: 1.8.0
Node version: 6.9.1
OS: Darwin 16.1.0 x64
```

I looked for other questions here on StackOverflow, but most of them were about having a proxy. I guess i don't have it, because the problem is happening in my house.

What should it be?

Comment: The resource you're looking for is very weird, it has lots of whitespaces. Exactly how does the command you're executing look like? `bower install flat-ui` or just `bower install`? It could be that your `bower.json` has become messed up with whitespaces.

Comment: Sorry, the command is correct. I messed up when pasting to StackOverflow

Comment: If you visit [this link](https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/flat-ui) *in your browser*, does it work? Or do you get an error? The reason I'm asking is to find out where the problem may lie. If you get the issue in your browser as well, there may be some DNS resolution issue.

Comment: Visiting the link in the browser returns me the correct json of the package. So strange.

Comment: Alright, now we know that the problem is with either Bower or Node.js itself. Which versions of each do you use? Could you try to upgrade Bower first (`npm i -g bower`) and run the command again. If that doesn't work, try upgrading Node.js to latest version and try again.

Comment: There also seems to be an [issue (#2391)](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/2392) with Bower that is similar to your error. They do suggest rolling back to 1.7.9 fixes the problem: `npm i -g bower@1.7.9`

Comment: Thank you so much. Updating node made it work!